# Layering multiple canvases using z-index doesn't show highest layer

Tags: html, html5-canvas, z-index

In HTML, I am trying to create one canvas that just displays an image with the colour black, and another canvas that displays a white border on top of the black canvas beneath it. Here's the HTML code:

```
<body>
<canvas width=600 height=400 style="position:absolute;background-image:url('Black.png');z-index:1;"
</canvas>
<canvas width=400 height=200 style="position:absolute;border:1px solid #FFFFFF;z-index:2;"
</canvas>
</body>
```

When I run the code in Google Chrome, I can only see the black background and no white border. What have I done wrong here? I tried searching for the problem but I didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you closing your canvas tags?

You have

```
<canvas width=600 height=400 style="position:absolute;background-image:url('Black.png');z-index:1;"
```

Try instead

```
<canvas width=600 height=400 style="position:absolute;background-image:url('Black.png');z-index:1;">
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your HTML is not well formatted.

This:

```
<canvas width=600 height=400 style="position:absolute;background-image:url('Black.png');z-index:1;"
```

Should be this:

```
<canvas width=600 height=400 style="position:absolute;background-image:url('Black.png');z-index:1;">
```